# How To Create A Circular Camera "Safe Frame"

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

I am working on an animation. The final output needs to be circular. I have a hard time seeing if my animation fits within the bounds of a circle while I work. I need a way to place a circular frame in front of my camera.

I have built a circular rig (pictured) but I have to key it separately from the camera and it becomes a pain to readjust the circular frame every time I move the camera.

What I need is a way to setup some kind of circular frame so that I do not have to readjust it every time I move the camera.

Thankyou in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: parent the circle to the camera so that everytime you move the camera the circle moves with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do what you want.

- Use an image.

Create an image that has the shape you want to use as "safety".

[image]

Then in the 3d vieport enable background images, select the image you created, set it to be used for camera view only. You can then choose to use it as background or foreground and adjust the opacity.

[image]

- Use a "child of" constraint.

Select the circle object, add a "child of" constraint. Select the camera to be used  as target. The circle will move to where the camera is located and will be rotated to match the camera rotation.

Manually postition the object so that is visible within the camera and scale it to your needs.

Since the object is parented to the camera, moving the camera will move the object as well.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! What an elegant solution. I was prepared for some ugly web of tracks, constraints, and empties.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood the question.

Activate the Turn around Camera (if u have 2.79 version from Addons)

Add camera align the camera. Click the object and from the toolshelf -> Animation click on the Turn around camera. And play the animation

[image]