# Custom Blender Camera Shape?

Tags: rendering, camera

Is it possible to have a *custom* Blender camera shape?

Like when rendering, the camera image outputs as a "triangle" shape? Or a polygon shape?

Is there a trick to making a custom picture shape without actually rendering a rectangle or a square?

The reason I am wondering is because [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NI3JyjiDCU) tutorial shows how to do it in OBS studio. So it might be possible to do in Blender.

If you know an answer, please share. I would really like to know.

Comment: Do you mean the shape in the viewport? Or some kind of clipping mask on top of the final image?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107326/how-to-create-a-circular-camera-safe-frame?rq=1

Comment: I think the holdout shader is what you want: [How to mask animated objects so they aren't visible past a certain area?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/how-to-mask-animated-objects-so-they-arent-visible-past-a-certain-area)

Comment: NO. I want the camera to have it's own shape.

Comment: Hello :). Your video output will *always* be rectangular. The linked tutorial is using a circular clipping mask over the rendered rectangular video, which you can do using compositor.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how to do that? I'm not experienced with the compositor, and I would like to learn.

Comment: See [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/how-to-mask-animated-objects-so-they-arent-visible-past-a-certain-area) in comment of @brockmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rendered video will always be rectangular.
But you can add a mask over it, using the compositor

1. Create a black and white image using Blender/Photoshop/whatever
2. Add an *RGB node*, using the *Mix node*
3. Connect your BW image into the FAC input

*How to connect a mask in compositor.

The RGB node changes the background color.*

[image]

Comment: *Or* you can use a holdout shader as mentioned in my comment, which also saves render time.